# Hide rows based upon table length

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic named range that grows and shrinks based upon a drop down selection. However, I only want to show the rows that contain the table and not all 147 rows (sometimes the table is only 4 rows long, sometimes it is 140). I need to hide the rows that do not contain data when a button is pressed. The table will always start in C176 and will only have 6 columns, the table will also never exceed rows 323.

Comment: Note that posting a list of requirements is not asking a question. We need to see what you have tried so far (see [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)). And a screenshot might help a lot here.

Answer (score 0):

Could you apply an autofilter in code and then use it to filter the blanks out?

Or you should loop the rows and check the cells for values and either hide / delete them but that would probably be a bit dirty

Comment: Hi michaelascend i don't want to use the autofilter as then i will have the filter drop downs in the range. Currently i have the below code which takes me to the last row but i now need to figure out how to hide the rows from that cell onwards.
range("C176").End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
range("activerow:323").EntireRow.Hidden = True

Comment: I'm with that first response, I need a bit more information and that last post didn't make sense compared to your first

Maybe I misread it, can you explain more